# Sharepoint 2013 - Importing and Exporting Navigation Terms

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, export, import, managed-navigation

Is there a way under site settings in SharePoint 2013 to import and export Navigation terms?  Do I need to download a separate app into SharePoint in order to complete this task?

I do not know PowerShell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no direct way to do this. PowerShell should be used or you should us custom code.

[This](http://sharepap.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/exporting-and-importing-managed.html) article give you step by step instruction to export managed terms.

[This](http://sharepap.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/importing-managed-metadata-termset-from.html) article give you step by step instruction to import managed terms.

Comment: Thank you Amal, do you also have a recommended article on how to enable or process a simple PowerShell request for beginners like myself?

Comment: You can start learning from [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee890108(v=office.15).aspx)